# Merge multiple data tables with duplicate column names

Tags: r, join, merge, duplicates, data.table

I am trying to merge (join) multiple data tables (obtained with fread from 5 csv files) to form a single data table. I get an error when I try to merge 5 data tables, but works fine when I merge only 4. MWE below:

```
# example data
DT1 <- data.table(x = letters[1:6], y = 10:15)
DT2 <- data.table(x = letters[1:6], y = 11:16)
DT3 <- data.table(x = letters[1:6], y = 12:17)
DT4 <- data.table(x = letters[1:6], y = 13:18)
DT5 <- data.table(x = letters[1:6], y = 14:19)

# this gives an error
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE, by = "x"), list(DT1, DT2, DT3, DT4, DT5))
```

> Error in merge.data.table(..., all = TRUE, by = "x") :  x has some
>   duplicated column name(s): y.x,y.y. Please remove or rename the 
>   duplicate(s) and try again.

```
# whereas this works fine
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE, by = "x"), list(DT1, DT2, DT3, DT4))

    x y.x y.y y.x y.y 
 1: a  10  11  12  13 
 2: b  11  12  13  14 
 3: c  12  13  14  15 
 4: d  13  14  15  16 
 5: e  14  15  16  17 
 6: f  15  16  17  18
```

I have a workaround, where, if I change the 2nd column name for DT1:

```
setnames(DT1, "y", "new_y")

# this works now
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE, by = "x"), list(DT1, DT2, DT3, DT4, DT5))
```

Why does this happen, and is there any way to merge an arbitrary number of data tables with the same column names without changing any of the column names?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28378637/reduce-in-r-over-similar-variable-names-causing-error

Comment: "Works fine"? Good luck with two `y.y`s, etc.

Comment: It looks like it happens because the `Reduce` function can't give a new column name. In other words, you run out of combinations of `x` and `y` (there are only 4 possible combinations so the error occurs when working with a 5th column).

Comment: @Frank Yes, but I can use setnames() after I get a merged data table (I read the 5 files always in a particular order), so that's not an issue for me.

Comment: @bourbaki4481472 that makes sense

Comment: @srao - that's a bad idea - do the `setnames` before/during the join, not after

Comment: Can the `x` vector contain repeated values? Is it identical in all `DT`s?

Comment: @Frank yes, `x` is exactly the same in all DTs. There are no repeated values.

Comment: @eddi setnames() during join would be my choice too, but how can I do that?

Comment: @srao if `x` is exactly the same for all of them, you shouldn't be merging

Comment: @eddi you're right, I can do `cbind` when `x` is exactly the same. I started using merge because I thought it would take care of any missing rows in some of the DTs, so yes, to clarify, `x` might not be the same in all DTs, but definitely has no repeated values. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @Frank see my comment above regarding `x`, sorry for mis-stating the case

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying. Although it's best to make your question representative of the problem you're actually facing, I think you got lucky this time and all the answers happen to still work in that case, except maybe the first part of Jaap's.

Comment: To be clear, you want multiple y columns with automatic names? Like `y.1 y.2 y.3 y.4 y.5`? And given you know that only column `y` is duplicated. So we don't need to auto-detect duplicate columns, and auto-rename/number them.

Comment: [`data.table::merge()` has an argument `suffixes = c(".x", ".y")`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.4-2/topics/merge), so you can avoid the rename step, just pass the corresponding number suffix already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a way of keeping a counter within `Reduce`, if you want to rename during the merge:

```
Reduce((function() {counter = 0
                    function(x, y) {
                      counter <<- counter + 1
                      d = merge(x, y, all = T, by = 'x')
                      setnames(d, c(head(names(d), -1), paste0('y.', counter)))
                    }})(), list(DT1, DT2, DT3, DT4, DT5))
#   x y.x y.1 y.2 y.3 y.4
#1: a  10  11  12  13  14
#2: b  11  12  13  14  15
#3: c  12  13  14  15  16
#4: d  13  14  15  16  17
#5: e  14  15  16  17  18
#6: f  15  16  17  18  19
```

Comment: What's up with the parentheses around and following the function definition, like `(function()...)()`?

Comment: @Frank it's a closure the outer function creates an environment, and returns the inner function, which is what those parentheses extract

Answer (score 9):

If it's just those 5 datatables (where `x` is the same for all datatables), you could also use nested joins:

```
# set the key for each datatable to 'x'
setkey(DT1,x)
setkey(DT2,x)
setkey(DT3,x)
setkey(DT4,x)
setkey(DT5,x)

# the nested join
mergedDT1 <- DT1[DT2[DT3[DT4[DT5]]]]
```

Or as @Frank said in the comments:

```
DTlist <- list(DT1,DT2,DT3,DT4,DT5)
Reduce(function(X,Y) X[Y], DTlist)
```

which gives:

```
   x y1 y2 y3 y4 y5
1: a 10 11 12 13 14
2: b 11 12 13 14 15
3: c 12 13 14 15 16
4: d 13 14 15 16 17
5: e 14 15 16 17 18
6: f 15 16 17 18 19
```

This gives the same result as:

```
mergedDT2 <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE, by = "x"), list(DT1, DT2, DT3, DT4, DT5))

> identical(mergedDT1,mergedDT2)
[1] TRUE
```

When your `x` columns do not have the same values, a nested join will not give the desired solution:

```
DT1[DT2[DT3[DT4[DT5[DT6]]]]]
```

this gives:

```
   x y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6
1: b 11 12 13 14 15 15
2: c 12 13 14 15 16 16
3: d 13 14 15 16 17 17
4: e 14 15 16 17 18 18
5: f 15 16 17 18 19 19
6: g NA NA NA NA NA 20
```

While:

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE, by = "x"), list(DT1, DT2, DT3, DT4, DT5, DT6))
```

gives:

```
   x y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6
1: a 10 11 12 13 14 NA
2: b 11 12 13 14 15 15
3: c 12 13 14 15 16 16
4: d 13 14 15 16 17 17
5: e 14 15 16 17 18 18
6: f 15 16 17 18 19 19
7: g NA NA NA NA NA 20
```

**Used data:**

In order to make the code with `Reduce` work, I changed the names of the `y` columns.

```
DT1 <- data.table(x = letters[1:6], y1 = 10:15)
DT2 <- data.table(x = letters[1:6], y2 = 11:16)
DT3 <- data.table(x = letters[1:6], y3 = 12:17)
DT4 <- data.table(x = letters[1:6], y4 = 13:18)
DT5 <- data.table(x = letters[1:6], y5 = 14:19)

DT6 <- data.table(x = letters[2:7], y6 = 15:20, key="x")
```

Comment: this is not the same as a `merge` with `all=TRUE`

Comment: Nothing surprising about it working on the toy example. The two will diverge once you add values of `x` that are not all identical between all 5. `merge` with `all = TRUE` does an outer join, whereas `[` does a one-sided one.

Comment: Your first one is aka `Reduce(function(X,Y) X[Y], DTlist)`

Comment: @eddi True, but the OP said in the comments that `x` is exactly the same for all DT's. I've updated my answer to show that with non-indetical `x` values this does not work.

Comment: ok, though if `x` is exactly the same, doing a merge is silly

Comment: @Frank Thanx, added it to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

**stack and reshape** I don't think this maps exactly to the `merge` function but...

```
mycols <- "x"
DTlist <- list(DT1,DT2,DT3,DT4,DT5)

dcast(rbindlist(DTlist,idcol=TRUE), paste0(paste0(mycols,collapse="+"),"~.id"))

#    x  1  2  3  4  5
# 1: a 10 11 12 13 14
# 2: b 11 12 13 14 15
# 3: c 12 13 14 15 16
# 4: d 13 14 15 16 17
# 5: e 14 15 16 17 18
# 6: f 15 16 17 18 19
```

I have no sense for if this would extend to having more columns than `y`.

**merge-assign**

```
DT <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE, by = mycols), 
  lapply(DTlist,`[.noquote`,mycols))

for (k in seq_along(DTlist)){
  js = setdiff( names(DTlist[[k]]), mycols )
  DT[DTlist[[k]], paste0(js,".",k) := mget(paste0("i.",js)), on=mycols, by=.EACHI]
}

#    x y.1 y.2 y.3 y.4 y.5
# 1: a  10  11  12  13  14
# 2: b  11  12  13  14  15
# 3: c  12  13  14  15  16
# 4: d  13  14  15  16  17
# 5: e  14  15  16  17  18
# 6: f  15  16  17  18  19
```

(I'm not sure if this fully extends to other cases. Hard to say because the OP's example really doesn't demand the full functionality of `merge`. In the OP's case, with `mycols="x"` and `x` being the same across all `DT*`, obviously a merge is inappropriate, as mentioned by @eddi. The general problem is interesting, though, so that's what I'm trying to attack here.)

Answer (score 3):

Using reshaping gives you a lot more flexibility in how you want to name your columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

list(DT1, DT2, DT3, DT4, DT5) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "source") %>%
  mutate(source = paste("y", source, sep = ".")) %>%
  spread(source, y)
```

Or, this would work

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

list(DT1 = DT1, DT2 = DT2, DT3 = DT3, DT4 = DT4, DT5 = DT5) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "source") %>%
  mutate(source = paste(source, "y", sep = ".")) %>%
  spread(source, y)
```

Comment: After the `bind_rows` there is no `source` column, so I see the `Error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'` (since `source` is a function). Not sure the fix for this... presumably you're misusing `bind_rows`...?

Comment: The .id feature is new in dplyr 0.4.3. Is that the version you are using?

Comment: Nope, 0.4.2. That must explain it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this:

```
dts <- list(DT1, DT2, DT3, DT4, DT5)

names(dts) <- paste("y", seq_along(dts), sep="")
data.table::dcast(rbindlist(dts, idcol="id"), x ~ id, value.var = "y")

#   x y1 y2 y3 y4 y5
#1: a 10 11 12 13 14
#2: b 11 12 13 14 15
#3: c 12 13 14 15 16
#4: d 13 14 15 16 17
#5: e 14 15 16 17 18
#6: f 15 16 17 18 19
```

The package name in "data.table::dcast" is added to ensure that the call returns a data table and not a data frame even if the "reshape2" package is loaded as well. Without mentioning the package name explicitly, the dcast function from the reshape2 package might be used which works on a data.frame and returns a data.frame instead of a data.table.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could `setNames` for the columns before and do `merge` like this

```
dts = list(DT1, DT2, DT3, DT4, DT5)
names(dts) = paste('DT', c(1:5), sep = '')    

dtlist = lapply(names(dts),function(i) 
         setNames(dts[[i]], c('x', paste('y',i,sep = '.'))))

Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = T), dtlist)

#   x y.DT1 y.DT2 y.DT3 y.DT4 y.DT5
#1: a    10    11    12    13    14
#2: b    11    12    13    14    15
#3: c    12    13    14    15    16
#4: d    13    14    15    16    17
#5: e    14    15    16    17    18
#6: f    15    16    17    18    19
```

Comment: Fyi, it is not necessary to give names to `dts`; you can already refer to them by `1:5`. Also, you probably want a `for` loop with `setnames`, not `setNames` (mentioned by eddi in a comment on the q and used by the op).

Comment: @Frank yes thanks! I just thought to include that step thinking if OP may want to put data.table names instead of just numbers, in that way the ultimate data.table would be more informative right

Comment: @Frank I didn't understand why for loop?

Comment: The `data.table` function `setnames` operates by reference, modifying the object itself, so there is no need to assign the function's value/result.

Comment: @Frank Oh, that's when I am using `data.table`'s `setnames` right.. OK cool!

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative solution - you can define join columns each time (when your x columns do not have the same values) . You need to define vectors with column names. Then you may chain joining by reference like this:

```
cols_dt1 <- colnames(dt_dt1)[!colnames(dt_dt1) %in% 'join_column1']
cols_dt2 <- colnames(dt_dt2)[!colnames(dt_dt2) %in% ' join_column2']
cols_dt3 <- colnames(dt_dt3)[!colnames(dt_dt3) %in% ' join_column3']
cols_dt4 <- colnames(dt_dt4)[!colnames(dt_dt4) %in% ' join_column4']
cols_dt5 <- colnames(dt_dt5)[!colnames(dt_dt5) %in% ' join_column5']

data_dt[dt_dt1, on=.( join_column1), (cols_dt1) := mget(cols_dt1)][
  dt_dt2, on=.( join_column2), (cols_dt2) := mget(cols_dt2)][
    dt_dt3, on=.( join_column3), (cols_dt3) := mget(cols_dt3)][
      dt_dt4, on=.( join_column4), (cols_dt4) := mget(cols_dt4)][
        dt_dt5, on=.( join_column5), (cols_dt5) := mget(cols_dt5)]
```