# Is it possible to merge mutiple data frames in R into one data where key is same for all the columns

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have been trying to merge multiple data.table into one data table. 
All the data tables have same key.

s1.dt,s2.dt and s3.dt are three data tables with common columns o and d.

Presently, I am doing it separately for the three data tables but in the entire data set, there are total of 100 data tables like these. 
So I was wondering if there is R function to do the same to avoid the tedious recurring code?

Here is my code:

```
s1.dt= data.table(s1, key = c("o","d"))

s2.dt= data.table(s2, key = c("o","d"))

s3.dt= data.table(s3, key = c("o","d"))

system.time(s12.dt<-merge(s1.dt,s2.dt,all = T, allow.cartesian = T ))

system.time(s123.dt<-merge(s12.dt,s3.dt,all = T, allow.cartesian = T ))
```

Comment: Fyi: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526889/merge-multiple-data-tables-with-duplicate-column-names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We keep the datasets in a `list` and use `Reduce` to `merge` all of them

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE, allow.cartesian = TRUE), 
                  list(s1.dt, s2.dt, s3.dt))
```

If there are many datasets, instead of typing object names to create the list, use either `paste` or `ls` with `mget`

```
mget(ls(pattern = "^s\\d+\\.dt$"))
```